# returning json from google calendar and parsing with php

Tags: php, json

```
$current = $_GET['current'];
$future = $_GET['future'];
//$CMD = $_GET['CMD'];

$current = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d",$current);

$future = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+7,date("Y"));
$futureDate = date("Y-m-d", $future);
//need to get the futureDate for URL
//$futrureDate = date("Y-m-d",$_GET['finalDate'])

// build feed URL
$googleURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-min=$currentDate&start-max=$futureDate/full?alt=json";
//$googleURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?alt=json";
//$url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json";
$data = file_get_contents($googleURL);
echo $data;
//$json = json_encode($data);
//echo $json;
//By default json_decode returns an stdClass object. You have to give a second parameter for this function TRUE.
$object = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($object->title[1]);

//echo $object->title[0];
```

Where do I put the alt=json in the url with the date variables. It works fine when i exclude the dates from the url but then its invalid with them.  also when i try to print a specific object i get an error that the object doesn't exist.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$googleURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-min=$currentDate&start-max=$futureDate/full&alt=json";
```

Comment: I tried that first and this is what i get     failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

It appears the URL scheme is asking for a basic view then adding the full view. (You can only have one.)

Try either:

```
$googleURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-min=$currentDate&start-max=$futureDate&alt=json";
```

or

```
$googleURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/full?start-min=$currentDate&start-max=$futureDate&alt=json";
```